# Router for url like domain.com/file.txt

Tags: router

I'm developing a custom module. The module has to respond to requests on `domain.com/file.txt`.

How can I configure a router for this path in `etc/config.xml`?

This is different from the usual router configuration XML, because there is no frontname and no controller in the path.

Comment: Why not use this? http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/optimise-web-s-mass-301-redirects.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're better off using a custom Router controller for that. [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-router-in-magento/) and [Atwix](http://www.atwix.com/magento/create-custom-router/) have both tutorials describing how to do this.

The one from Atwix explains the easiest. Your `Router.php` would look something like this

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard
{
    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)
    {
        if ($request->getPathInfo() == 'file.txt')
        {
           $request->setModuleName('[module]')
               ->setControllerName('index')
               ->setActionName('index');

           return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return parent::match($request);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: One side-note, this only works if file.txt doesn't exist, or is explicitly rewritten to Magento's index.php. So if it doesn't seem to work, check for it's existence.

Comment: @Melvyn Depends on the server configuration. I redirect all requests to index.php, disregarding any file existence.

Comment: @i.amniels I assume you make exceptions for /skin, /js and /media at least. :)

Comment: @Melvyn No, those are handled by the CDN.

Answer (score 1):

You can think about a url_rewrite for this. Just add a rewrite, then magento will resolve the correct controller for you!

Comment: Or Fabians route http://www.byte.nl/blog/create-bulk-301-redirects-in-magento/